# How do I select a specific id from td element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pulling data from an api using jquery with the following code

```
 type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/teams",

                    processData: true,
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        var trHTML = '';
                        $.each(data.teams, function (key, item) {
                            var id = item._links.self.href;
                            var indexOfLastBackSlash = id.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
                            id = id.substring(indexOfLastBackSlash);
                            //$('<option>', { text: item.TeamName, id: item.ID }).appendTo('#lstTeams');
                            var $row = $("<tr>", { class: "info" });
                            $row.append($("<td>").html(item.name));
                            $row.append($("<td>").html(item.code));
                            $row.append($("<td>").html(item.shortName));
                            $row.append($("<td>").html(item.squadMarketValue));
                            $row.append($("<td>").html(item.crestURL));
                            $row.append($("<td>").html(id));
                            $row.appendTo($('#teamsTable'));
```

I want to select a row by clicking on a td element and get the id and place it in a url. I have tried this

```
$("#teamsTable").on('click', 'td', (function() {
                                //var id = $(this).attr("id");
                                //location.reload();
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'GET',
                                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                                    crossDomain: true,
                                    url: "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/" + id + "/fixtures",
```

But it seems to select all ids from the table. Any suggestions how to grab just the one id?

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr')` will get the closest row.  `.parent()` also works here.  I like `.closest()` because it is more versatile.  It basically starts searching upward (up the DOM tree) until it finds a `tr`.  The opposite is `.find(...)` which searches downward (into the nested objects).

Comment: In your API call part, it doesn't look like you assign any ids to TRs or TDs.  I would suggest putting the id on the TR if it applies to the whole row.  (something like `$row.prop('id',id);` )

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

You should be able to

```
var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JWhite18/r5b51g83/) for example

Edit: To @James' point in the comment.

```
var $row = $("<tr>", { class: "info" }).prop('id', id);
```